# VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error with Virutalised existing linux partition

Tags: linux, virtualbox, windows-8.1

I have installed both ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1 on my harddrive but due to certain circumstances I need to virtualize my linux partition. I have been able to login successfully into it but then ...
[image]

The first time I did this it when right to the login screen. Found this thread 
[VM on RAW disk on Windows 7 host](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=38914#p175089)
which suggest that I should use `Diskpart` to run the command `ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY` I wonder whether it is necessary and whether it's a good idea as this is my output from `ATTRIBUTES DISK`[image: output from ATTRIBUTES DISK].

I'd hate to make a stupid mistake right now. So can anyone help me out with this error?

**EDIT**

- Tried it though. Got an error 
  `Diskpart failed to clear disk attributes`
- Disabled UAC

Answer (score 1):

I had to go into virtual machine’s settings> storage> SATA controller> check use host i/o cache.